# No sound, only 'HDMI Output' shown in Volume Control, no way to load the onboard sound device ('Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS')

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

Several days ago my laptop stopped playing or recording sound. I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04, to no avail.

The Volume Control shows different 'HDMI output' profiles (linked to the `NVIDIA TU106 High Definition Audio` card) but fails to show any analog sound profiles.

I have two cards:

```
lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Lake PCH cAVS
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16
        Memory at da210000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Memory at da100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller
        Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 16
        Memory at da21c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
--
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company TU106 High Definition Audio Controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
        Memory at dc080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

...but only one is used:

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I tried to force the loading of the Intel card driver in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf with:

```
options snd_hda_intel enable=1,0 vid=8086,10de pid=a348,10f9
options snd_hda_intel index=0 vid=8086 pid=a348
options snd_hda_intel index=1
```

...but no joy.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

[This post on Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2421187) fixed it for me:

> 1. First of all, by looking at the output of `cat /proc/asound/card0/codec*` it was obvious something was wrong... So first to fix that I had to edit the file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` to add the line: `options snd-hda-intel probe_mask=0x1` . After reboot, then I could see everything the output of `cat /proc/asound/card0/codec*` that was looking perfect but still no sound. At least, things had improved a little bit now;
> 2. As shown by the output of `cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec`, my HD Audio Codec is ALC1220 so I went here to look at what specific model that corresponded. My laptop is a clevo laptop ("clevo-p950", in the list), so I added the line `options snd-hda-intel model=clevo-p950` to the the `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` file and rebooted. I thought I had solved it at this point but... nope, still no sound from the speakers or the headphones... but then;
> 3. After I posted a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1833161), someone suggested that I upgrade my kernel version to at least 5.0. So if you are in this situation where you think you should proceed with a kernel upgrade and it's your first time, don't worry, it's not hard to do at all. I used to build my kernel from source (which can be a long process depending on your machine) but now there's a nice GUI and debian packages to help you out, this tool is Ukuu, see [this article](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/get-the-latest-linux-kernel-version-in-ubuntu/) for example... In my case and at this moment of writing, after a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 install and update, the kernel version was 4.18.0-22 which was not able to make the "clevo-p950" option work. So I upgraded my kernel to 5.0.2, rebooted and everything started to work! Now my microphone, my headphone and my speakers are all working. This is nice! I hope this can help somebody! Good luck!